# Integrating Behave or Lettuce with Python unittest

Tags: python, lettuce, python-behave

I'm looking at BDD with Python. Verification of results is a drag, because the results being verified are not printed on failure.

Compare Behave output:

```
AssertionError: 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\behave\model.py", line 1456, in run
    match.run(runner.context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\behave\model.py", line 1903, in run
    self.func(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "steps\EcuProperties.py", line 28, in step_impl
    assert vin == context.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='infoTable']/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]").text
```

to SpecFlow+NUnit output:

```
Scenario: Verify VIN in Retrieve ECU properties -> Failed on thread #0
    [ERROR]   String lengths are both 16. Strings differ at index 15.
  Expected: "ABCDEFGH12345679"
  But was:  "ABCDEFGH12345678"
  --------------------------^
```

Finding failure causes is way faster with the SpecFlow output. To get the variable contents on error, they have to be put into a string manually.

From the [Lettuce tutorial](http://lettuce.it/tutorial/simple.html#lettuce-id4):

```
assert world.number == expected, \
    "Got %d" % world.number
```

From the [Behave tutorial](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/tutorial.html#step-parameters):

```
if text not in context.response:
    fail('%r not in %r' % (text, context.response))
```

Compare this to [Python unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html):

```
self.assertEqual('foo2'.upper(), 'FOO')
```

resulting in:

```
Failure
Expected :'FOO2'
Actual   :'FOO'
 <Click to see difference>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in test_upper
    self.assertEqual('foo2'.upper(), 'FOO')
AssertionError: 'FOO2' != 'FOO'
```

However, the methods from Python unittest cannot be used outside a `TestCase` instance.

Is there a good way of getting all the niceness of Python unittest integrated into Behave or Lettuce?

Comment: I am using `pytest` which seems to provide all the needed context information on failure. No need to code printing it out, just make the assertion and let `pytest` to print it.
I would try letuce using with pytest, but I do not have any letuce or behave test case. Can you provide some short selfcontaining example?

Comment: A short self-containing example can be found at the very beginning of the Behave tutorial: https://pythonhosted.org/behave/tutorial.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) includes a package that takes all the class-based asserts that `unittest` provides and turns them into plain functions, the module's [documentation states](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html?highlight=nose.tools#module-nose.tools):

> The nose.tools module provides [...] all of the same `assertX` methods found in `unittest.TestCase` (only spelled in [PEP 8#function-names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008#function-names) fashion, so `assert_equal` rather than `assertEqual`).

For instance:

```
from nose.tools import assert_equal

@given("foo is 'blah'")
def step_impl(context):
    assert_equal(context.foo, "blah")
```

You can ad custom messages to assertions just like you would with the `.assertX` methods of `unittest`.

That's what I use for the test suites that I run with Behave.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the `nose.tools` equivalent of `unittest`'s `self.fail()`?

Comment: I don't think `nose.tools` has a direct equivalent to `self.fail()`. Is there something that `self.fail()` does that a plain `assert False, "message"` does not? It is clear that the `self.assertX` methods are better than a plain `assert` because they provide intelligent diagnosis information without having to write custom error messages. I'm not seeing the same advantage for `self.fail()`.

Comment: fail() is more consistent with the assert_x methods. fail() also signals the intention explicitly to maintenance programmers. Thanks anyway!